# Eclipselink mixing annotation and xml

Tags: xml, jpa, orm, annotations, eclipselink

My target is to save some converters & named queries declaration in eclipselink-orm.xml. and use the annotation @convert within entities implementation, call the named queries inside EJB.

- List item : `<converter name="date-time-converter" class="domaine.dateTimeConverter/>`
- annotation `@convert("date-time-converter")`

eclipse shows me an error : *The attribute value is undefined for the annotation type Convert*

how to implement it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The annotation `@Convert` does not have an attribute "*value*". You need to define the "*converter*" attribute, as

```
@Convert(converter=DateTimeConverter.class)
MyDateTime dateTime;
```

as per the [javadocs for JPA 2.1](http://www.datanucleus.org/javadocs/javax.persistence/2.1/javax/persistence/Convert.html). You can see use of JPA AttributeConverter on [this link](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_5_0/jpa/mapping.html#attributeconverter). The `@Converter` is to define whether it is autoApply. If so, then you don't need the `@Convert` against a field. The same applies if using orm.xml

Comment: thx Very helpful, actually i use _eclipselink_ but i think that **_datanucleus_** is a serious alternative.